# Zooming SVG images at flex side

Tags: apache-flex, svg

Following are sub-parts of my question:

1. How can I send generated svg file from server (java) to client(flex)?
   (Should I send it as ByteArray or use some other method?)
2. How can I display this svg from flex?
   (Should I just set the source property of image file svg as xml?)
3. How can I zoom this svg from flex side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I send generated svg file from server (java) to client(flex)?
>   (Should I send it as ByteArray or use some other method?)

SVG is a text format; so if you're looking for an easy way to send it over the wire; I'd use text.

> How can I display this svg from flex? (Should I just set the source
>   property of image file svg as xml?)

SVG is not a native format to the Flash Player.  I think you'll need to build an ActionScript based SVG renderer/viewer to do anything with an SVG viewer in a Flash Platform app.  [Here is one such library](http://odd.ness.io/category/svg-viewer).

I believe the Flex compiler can do some magic on SVG to make it into something usable in Flex.  [More info about that here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html).  You have to embed the SVG graphic at compile time; it won't do anything at runtime.

You may be able to compile the SVG to a SWF on the server using command line tools and then have your Flex app load the SWF.

> How can I zoom this svg from flex side?

Once you figure out how you want to display it as a Flex Component, you can use the [scaleX](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#scaleX), [scaleY](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#scaleY), and [scaleZ](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#scaleZ) properties to zoom in or out.